# Add a delete button to Todo list

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to JavaScript and I'm making a simple todo list. I added a delete button to delete the tasks when I click it; but having a hard time figuring out how to add the functionality. How can I do that?

Here is my code:

```
`const list = [];

function addItem() {
    task = document.getElementById('add').value;
    list.push(task);
    if (task == "") {
        alert("Please enter a task")
        return true;
    }
    document.getElementById('unList').innerHTML += `<li> ${task} <button type='button'     onclick='change(this)'>done</button><button type='button' onclick='removeItem(this)'>delete</button>    </li>`
}

function change(e) {
    e.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
}
function removeItem() {

}
function clearField() {
    document.getElementById('add').value = "";
    document.getElementById('add').focus();

}
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <p>
            <h1 id="title">
                Todo List
            </h1>
            <h2 id="date">

            </h2>
            </p>
            <form name="myForm" method="post" action="">
                <input type="text" id="add" name="addNew">
                <button name="sumbitBtn" type="button" class="addBtn" onclick="addItem();   clearField();" >add</button>
            <div>
                <ul id="unList">
                </ul>
        </form>
    </header>
</div>
</div>
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing some closing tags and using some unnecessary ones for this purpose. `<header>` is part of an `<article>` and `<form>` is to send the data.

I've changed a few things. Just trying to show you a way to do it. I hope it helps.

```js
let editing;

function addItem() {
  const input = document.getElementById('new-item');
  const task = input.value;

  if (!task) {
      alert("Please enter a task")
      return;
  }
  
  const list = document.getElementById('todo-list');
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  const span = document.createElement('span');
  
  span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(task));
  li.appendChild(span);

  const buttonEdit = createButton('edit', () => {
    input.value = task;
    
    document.getElementById('change').disabled = false;
  
    editing = span;
    input.focus();
  });
  li.appendChild(buttonEdit);
  
  const buttonDelete = createButton('delete', () => {
    list.removeChild(li);
  });
  li.appendChild(buttonDelete);

  list.appendChild(li);

  clearField();
}


function createButton(text, onclick) {
  const button = document.createElement('button');
  button.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
  button.onclick = onclick;
  return button;
}

function change(e) {
  const input = document.getElementById('new-item');
  const task = input.value;
  
  editing.innerText = task;
  
  clearField();
}

function clearField() {
  const input = document.getElementById('new-item');
  input.value = "";
  editing = undefined;
  
  document.getElementById('change').disabled = true;
  
  input.focus();
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 id="title">Todo List</h1>

  <input type="text" id="new-item">

  <button id="add" onclick="addItem();">add</button>
  <button id="change" onclick="change();" disabled>change</button>
  
  <ul id="todo-list"></ul>
</div>
```